# Docker build fails with error "Unable to locate package" when trying to set up local node pool for Hyperledger Indy on MacOS m1

Tags: macos, docker, apple-m1, hyperledger-indy

I have been wanting to play around with Hyperledger Indy, and I seem to have gotten the necessary sdk installed correctly. However, when I go to build the docker image for a local node pool, I keep getting this error:

[image]

And here is the dockerfile:

[dockerfile](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/ci/indy-pool.dockerfile)

I'm hoping this is something simple that I'm just not yet sophisticated enough to realize.

Comment: I don't think that's whole error message, can you share whole output from the terminal in the plain text format?!